# Set a limit on how much a log batch can grow

Tags: c#, nlog

I'm using NLog to process log messages in a large production environment. The following function creates the NLog configuration object. I really need all log messages to be logged, so I cannot have log messages being dropped. Therefore, I have set the `OverflowAction` of the `AsyncTargetWrapper` to `Grow`. The problem however, is that Azure TableStorage has a limit of 1,000 records per batch. If I try to save 1,001 messages in a batch, nothing is saved. I cannot find how to configure NLog to cap the growth on 1,000 and do a flush once this value has been reached. Apart from that, regular flushing happens all the while, but since our applications do a lot of logging, it is well possible that the grown batch might exceed the 1,000 logs limit of Azure TableStorage.

How can I configure NLog to safely save all logs to TableStorage, considering the 1,000 record limit of Azure TableStorage?

```
public static LoggingConfiguration SetupLoggingConfiguration(
    string instrumentationKey,
    string tableStorageConnectionString,
    LogLevel appInsightsLogLevel,
    LogLevel tableStorageLogLevel)
{
    var config = new LoggingConfiguration();

    // Targets
    var applicationInsightsTarget = new ApplicationInsightsTarget()
    {
        Name = nameof(ApplicationInsightsTarget),
        InstrumentationKey = instrumentationKey,
        Layout = "${longdate}|${level:uppercase=true}|${logger}|${message}"
    };

    var tableStorageTarget = new TableStorageTarget()
    {
        Name = nameof(TableStorageTarget),
        Layout = "${callsite:cleanNamesOfAnonymousDelegates=true}:${callsite-linenumber}${newline}Stack Trace:${stacktrace}",
        ConnectionString = tableStorageConnectionString,
        OptimizeBufferReuse = true,
        TableName = "Logs"
    };

    var tableStorageWrapper = new AsyncTargetWrapper()
    {
        WrappedTarget = tableStorageTarget,
        QueueLimit = 500,
        OverflowAction = AsyncTargetWrapperOverflowAction.Grow
    };

    // Rules
    config.AddRule(appInsightsLogLevel, LogLevel.Fatal, applicationInsightsTarget);
    config.AddRule(tableStorageLogLevel, LogLevel.Fatal, tableStorageWrapper);

    return config;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your TableStorageTarget comes from https://www.nuget.org/packages/NLog.Extensions.AzureStorage/ , then it is impossible for it to save more than 100 records at a time. So your issue with 1001 records must be something else.

`AsyncTargetWrapper` has a parameter called `BatchSize`, that controls how many logevents it posts to the destination target. The default value is 200 logevents in NLog ver. 4.5.8

But if you perform explicit Flush in NLog then it will trigger the `AsyncTargetWrapper` to flush all its pending logevents independent of `BatchSize`. I guess this could be changed by making a PullRequest for the NLog-project. But one should avoid calling NLog Flush, and only call it at special circumstances (Ex. shutdown).

Comment: Indeed, I do use the mentioned package from jdetmar. Thanks for your answer, I'll check it out and reply and add votes once the issue is found.